# If $g(\cdot)$ is a strictly increasing, strictly concave function does $m$ such that $g(a+(1-m).b)=c. g(a+b/c) + (1-c). g(a)$ increase with $b$?

Tags: calculus, functions

Suppose $g: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ is a continuously differentiable, strictly increasing, strictly concave function, with a strictly convex first derivative. Suppose also that $a>0$, $b>0$ and $0<c<1$.

It is trivial that:

$g(a+b) > c. g(a+b/c)  + (1-c) .g(a)$

Define $m$ to be such that:

$g(a+(1-m).b)=c. g(a+b/c)  + (1-c). g(a)$

For $a$, $b$ and $c$, I can prove that $m$ exists, that it is unique and that $0<m<1$. But I would like to know how $m$ varies with $b$. In other words, for $b'>b$, is $m'>m$? Where $m'$ is such that

$g(a+(1-m').b')=c. g(a+b'/c)  + (1-c). g(a)$

If not, what would be a counterexample?

Thanks in advance!